# Write SQL query that finds the most common first name(S), errors

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to write a query that finds the most common first names, given a table called USERS_FAKE U.

My problem is I only managed to write a query that returns ONLY 1 common first name. But if the name "Bob" shows up 6 times, making it the most common first name, and there's also other names that show up 6 times (like "Mike"), my query will only return "Bob". My query should return Bob and Mike, since they have the same number of occurrences.

Attempt at MCRE:

```
-- The table we are working with
CREATE TABLE USERS_FAKE (
    USER_ID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
    FIRST_NAME VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
    LAST_NAME VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL
);

-- Test Data, to test that we return the Most Common First Name(s)
-- (clearly there are 2 Most Common First Name(s): Bob and Mike)
INSERT INTO USERS_FAKE VALUES(5,  'Bob',  'Io');
INSERT INTO USERS_FAKE VALUES(6,  'Bob',  'Io');
INSERT INTO USERS_FAKE VALUES(7,  'Bob',  'Io');
INSERT INTO USERS_FAKE VALUES(8,  'Bob',  'Io');
INSERT INTO USERS_FAKE VALUES(9,  'Bob',  'Io');
INSERT INTO USERS_FAKE VALUES(10, 'Bob',  'Io');
INSERT INTO USERS_FAKE VALUES(11, 'Mike',  'Ganymede');
INSERT INTO USERS_FAKE VALUES(12, 'Mike',  'Ganymede');
INSERT INTO USERS_FAKE VALUES(13, 'Mike',  'Ganymede');
INSERT INTO USERS_FAKE VALUES(14, 'Mike',  'Ganymede');
INSERT INTO USERS_FAKE VALUES(15, 'Mike',  'Ganymede');
INSERT INTO USERS_FAKE VALUES(16, 'Mike',  'Ganymede');
```

I need to write a simple query that uses aggregation + `WHERE` clause, but you combine the two in SQL. This is in Oracle, and I have to use `ROWNUM`, `LIMIT` does not work in my environment.

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @Strawberry Thanks, I just added a MCRE

Comment: @McFloofenbork Why did you remove your attempted solution?

Comment: @Barmar I thought it made the post too convoluted.

Comment: No, it's a necessary part of the [mcve]. You show what you tried, then we show how to fix it.

Comment: @Barmar OK, next time I will not do that. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregation isn't allowed in the `WHERE` clause. You wanted the query to return the name associated to the count of occurrences of the most frequent names. Instead a `HAVING` clause should be used because the `HAVING` clause is used to filter groups after the aggregation in SQL.

See below example:

```
SELECT DISTINCT FIRST_NAME, COUNT(FIRST_NAME) AS MOST_FREQUENT 
FROM USERS_FAKE
GROUP BY FIRST_NAME
HAVING COUNT(FIRST_NAME) = (SELECT COUNT(FIRST_NAME) AS NUM_FREQUENCY 
                            FROM USERS_FAKE
                            GROUP BY FIRST_NAME
                            ORDER BY NUM_FREQUENCY DESC
                            LIMIT 1)
;
```

Also I personally recommend `row_number()`:

```
SELECT T.FIRST_NAME
FROM (
       SELECT N.FIRST_NAME AS FIRST_NAME
            , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY N.NUM_FREQUENCY DESC) AS ROW_NUM
       FROM (
               SELECT FIRST_NAME
                    , COUNT(FIRST_NAME) AS NUM_FREQUENCY 
               FROM USERS_FAKE
               GROUP BY FIRST_NAME
               ORDER BY NUM_FREQUENCY
            ) AS N
      ) AS T
WHERE T.ROW_NUM = 1
;
```

The `ROW_NUMBER()` ranks the names by their occurrence then the query returns the first row which is related to the most frequent name. In this case, `ROW_NUMBER()` is not the best solution. However, it can be an easy way to implement the "occurrence matters" scenarios.

Comment: Thanks, yours was closest to my needed answer. I changed the first code's `LIMIT 1` to `FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT n.first
FROM names n
JOIN ( SELECT first, COUNT(*) AS cnt
       FROM names
       GROUP BY first
     ) n1 ON ( n1.first = n.first )
ORDER BY n1.cnt DESC group by n.first;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use RANK() function

```
SELECT   t.first_name, t.count FROM
 (
   SELECT
   first_name, COUNT(1) AS count,
   RANK () OVER (  ORDER BY COUNT(1) DESC ) rank_no 
   FROM USERS_FAKE
   GROUP BY first_name
 ) AS t
 WHERE rank_no = 1
```